# 2014 moto x battery life

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, moto-x

I'm experiencing an issue with my 2014 Moto X's battery running Android 5.1 and I was wondering if someone have any suggestions or something ...

for example, yesterday I had about 30% left of my battery when I launched "Real Racing 3" game to play and right before game even get to load, my phone powered itself off( since it was on 30% mark before, I decided to start it again, one phone finished booting I noticed my 30% went down to 5% and shortly after that phone powered itself off again, when I plugged in my phone into a charger and almost immediately my phone reported 30% mark on my battery...

today i let my battery completely die (it was about 10% when phone powered itself off) and I just finished charging it completely as well, but something tells me that isn't gonna fix anything...

any advise?

Comment: If it was a chinese battery, don't be suprised. they are... Erratic. Either way, you need a new battery.

Comment: @DanB pretty much all batteries out there are Chinese, especially that my phone was purchased directly from Motorola and Motorola a part of Lenovo (Chinese company) so again _NO_ surprise there...

Answer (score 0):

Even though you already drained the battery and recharged it, I would recommend doing it once more (except let the phone die), just to recalibrate the battery. After that, check out what is eating up your battery in the settings. Try playing with the different radios (BT, WiFi) and seeing what effect each one has. If all of these don't work, try getting a new battery under warrenty or buying one and replacing it yourself (I would try [Motorola Moto X 2nd Generation Battery Replacement - iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Motorola+Moto+X+2nd+Generation+Battery+Replacement/40717))

If ALL of these don't work, then 5.1 is messing with your phone (even though I have a Moto X running 5.1) and try installing a rom of 5.0.1 or even something else like cyanogenmod.

Good Luck!